# Outputting Blum Integers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_integer),

> In mathematics, a natural number \$n\$ is a Blum integer if \$n = p \times q\$ is a semiprime for which \$p\$ and \$q\$ are distinct prime numbers congruent to \$3 \bmod 4\$. That is, \$p\$ and \$q\$ must be of the form \$4t + 3\$, for some integer \$t\$. Integers of this form are referred to as Blum primes. This means that the factors of a Blum integer are Gaussian primes with no imaginary part.

The first few Blum integers are:

```
21, 33, 57, 69, 77, 93, 129, 133, 141, 161, 177, 201, 209, 213, 217, 237, 249, 253, 301, 309, 321, 329, 341, 381, 393, 413, 417, 437, 453, 469, 473, 489, 497, 501, 517, 537, 553, 573, 581, 589, 597, 633, 649, 669, 681, 713, 717, 721, 737, 749, 753, 781, 789
```

This is [OEIS A016105](https://oeis.org/A016105)

Your task is to make a program that does one of the following:

- Take an index \$n\$ and output the \$n^{th}\$ Blum integer, either 0 or 1 indexing.
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ Blum integers.
- Output all Blum integers infinitely.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer wins.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 65 bytes

```python
n=1
while[[d%4for d in range(2,n)if n%d<1]==[3,3]!=print(n)]:n+=4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WkKs8IzMnNTo6RdUkLb9IIUUhM0@hKDEvPVXDSCdPMzNNIU81xcYw1tY22ljHOFbRtqAoM69EI08z1ipP29bk/38A)

Prints indefinitely. Identifies Blum integers as those with exactly two proper factors, both of which are 3 mod 4.

Comment: This is amazing. How does the `!=print(n)` work?

Comment: @Wasif `print` returns None, so we check if the condition on the left (equality) is not None, i.e. we loop while the two factors are congruent to 3 mod 4.

Comment: @Wasif It's [inequality short-circuiting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211783/20260).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆḌ%4Ḅ⁼13µ#
```

A full program accepting an integer, \$n\$, from STDIN, that prints a list of the first \$n\$ Blum integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28MdPaomD3e0PGrcY2h8aKvy//9GpgYA)**

#### How?

First, note that a semi-prime has exactly three proper divisors: \$(1, p, q)\$, thus Blum integers may be identified by having \$X=(1\mod 4, p\mod 4, q\mod 4)\$ equal to \$(1,3,3)\$.

Next, note that if we treat \$X\$ as a binary number then Blum integers all evaluate to:
\$2^2\cdot 1 + 2^1\cdot 3 + 2^0\cdot 3=13\$

Next, note that the only way to have a string of \$[0..3]\$ evaluate as \$13\$ this way is to have either three or four proper divisors. Two is too few since \$2^1\cdot 3+2^0\cdot 3<13\$ and five is too many since \$2^4\cdot 1>13\$ and the smallest proper divisor is always \$1\$.

Lastly, note that the only numbers with exactly four proper divisors are fourth powers of primes, with proper divisors of \$(1, p, p^2, p^3)\$. Since \$p\mod 4\$ is never zero \$(1, 0, 1, 3)\$ and \$(1, 0, 2, 1)\$ cannot happen, so the only possible false positive that could exist after taking modulo four would be \$(1, 1, 0, 1)\$, but if \$p\equiv 1\pmod 4\$ then \$p^2\equiv 1\pmod 4\$, so that cannot happen either.

```
ÆḌ%4Ḅ⁼13µ# - Main Link: no arguments
        µ# - read n from STDIN, count up from k=0
             finding the first n k for which this f(k) is truthy:
ÆḌ         -   proper divisors
  %4       -   mod four
    Ḅ      -   convert from binary
     ⁼13   -   equals 13?
```

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
(>:[]echo~~:/@q:*3 3-:4|q:)^:_@3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxCsJAEET7fMVgc0YuZ/Y25shCQlCwEgtbUQsxiI2kl/z6uVvsG2befvIquAm9wMGjhuhVAYfL6ZjXg1xvr@f7uyyyHWfZMLiS5jdLeZfHyLkszGKCc8V5HxDJg9ljlzzaziNpdtopaiEz1OgLtQaTsSaD2khssI1T/gM)

Outputs all Blum primes.

- `^:_@3` Starting with 3, and continuing to a fixed point (which will never be reached)...
- `]echo~~:/@q:*3 3-:4|q:` If the the current number `n`'s prime factors mod 4 exactly matches `3 3`, and the numbers are not equal `~:/@q:*`, then `echo n` as a side effect...
- `>:[` Return `n+1` for the next iteration.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)!

Prints the infinite list of Blum numbers.

```
∞ʒfʒ4%Í}ü*θyQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSZsqSNCXDjX3DvCrOuHlR//8)

```python
∞                 # infinite list of positive integers [1,2,...
 ʒ                # filter, keep y if
  f               #   push list of unique prime factors
   ʒ4%Í}          #   keep those where k%4-2==1
        ü*        #   get the products of all adjacent factors
          θ       #   take the last one (or the empty list if there are none)
           yQ     #   is this equal to y?
```

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing ``0s`*`` with `ü*θ`

Comment: @Adnan thanks a lot, for some reason I thought this wouldn't work if there are less than 2 prime factors

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>61</s> 56 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```r
while(T<-T+1)if(all(which(!T%%2:T)%%4==c(2,2,0)))show(T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDMzTSMxJ0cDKJacoaEYoqpqZBWiqapqYmubrGGkY6RjoKmpWZyRX64Rovn/PwA)

Outputs all Blum integers infinitely.

#### Explanation

As R doesn't have build-ins for prime factorisation we have to circumvent this.

Let's notice that:

- Blum integer needs to have exactly three non-trivial factors (prime or not) - including the number itself;
- The remainders \$ mod\ 4 \$ need to be \$3,3,1\$ respecitvely.

Therefore it suffices to check if the divisors of the number (`which(!T%%2:T)` is off-by-one) are `all` equal \$ mod\ 4 \$ to vector `[3 3 1]` (`c(2,2,0)` correcting the off-by-one).

<sup>Actually we could skip testing the number itself for mod4, but, you know, bytes...</sup>

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - good catch! The `identical` would be necessary when checking only proper divisors (to check both length and values), as I had in one of the first attempts. Now, when checking also the number itself, `all` with `==` suffices indeed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
∞››'Ǐ'›4Ḋ;÷*=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%9E%E2%80%BA%E2%80%BA%27%C7%8F%27%E2%80%BA4%E1%B8%8A%3B%C3%B7*%3D&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Prints infinitely.

```
∞››           # Positive integers (except 1)
   '          # Filtered by
    Ǐ         # Prime factors
     '   ;    # Filtered by
      ›       # Incremented 
       4Ḋ     # Is divisible by 4?
          ÷   # Push all to the stack separately
           *  # Product of the top two
            = # Is equal to (implicit input / another factor)
```

Let's go through the outcomes after ÷.

Case 1: 1 factor left. This gets multiplied by the original number, and since it's not 1, it can never equal the original number.

Case 2: 2 factors left. These two get multiplied together, and if it's the same as the original, it will be outputted.

Case 3: 3+ factors left. The top two will be multiplied, but can't equal the third because it's a prime.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 78 bytes

```
\d*$
_
"$&"}/(^_|\1__)+$|^(__(___?)?(____)*)\2+$|^(?!(___(____)*)\5+$)/+`$
_
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqqHhnvA/JkVLhSueS0lFTalWXyMuvibGMD5eU1ulJk4jPh6I4u017UFUvKaWZowRWNxeESQAFzTVVtHU104AmRL//78Jl6EJl5EJl7EJl4kJAA) Link includes test cases. Outputs the `n`th term. Explanation:

```
"$&"}`
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
\d*$
_
```

Delete the numeric input, and increment the result.

```
/(^_|\1__)+$|^(__(___?)?(____)*)\2+$|^(?!(___(____)*)\5+$)/+`
```

While the result: `(^_|\1__)+$` is square, or `^(__(___?)?(____)*)\2+$` contains a nontrivial proper factor that is not of the form `4t+3`, or `(?!(___(____)*)\5+$)` does not contain a nontrivial proper factor that is of the form `4t+3`, then...

```
$
_
```

... increment the result.

```
_
```

Convert to decimal.

All numbers contain a trivial factor not of the form `4t+3`, i.e. 1. Since the product of two factors `4t+3` would be of the form `4t+1`, the only way a number to only contain nontrivial factors of the form `4t+3` is for the number to be a prime of the form `4t+3`. The next step is to consider numbers with nontrivial proper factors which are all of the form `4t+3`. This set contains only products of two primes of the form `4t+3` (since 3 primes would generate nontrivial proper factors of the form `4t+1` as the product of two of the primes), so it remains to exclude perfect squares which then leaves Blum integers.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>10</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

-1 thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan) (`26` is a built-in, `₂`, and `1` is the only truthy integer in 05AB1E)

A port of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230083/53748), just using divisors rather than proper divisors.

```
∞ʒÑ4%JC27Q
```

A full program printing an infinite list of the Blum integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MOTzRR9XJ@1NSk@/8/AA)**

#### How?

For an explanation of why this works see [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230083/53748) (and add \$(p\cdot q)\mod 4\$ to the list to be converted from binary, noting that this will be \$1\$ for a Blum integer, while \$13\cdot2+1=27\$ and the existence of two final potential false-positives, \$(1,1,0,0,3)\$ and \$(1,1,0,1,1)\$ neither of which can happen since \$p\equiv 1\pmod 4 \implies p^2\equiv 1\pmod 4\$.)

```
∞ʒÑ4%JC₂-
∞         - the positive integers
 ʒ        - filter keep if truthy under:
  Ñ       -   divisors
   4      -   push four
    %     -   modulo
     J    -   join
      C   -   from binary -> x
       ₂  -   push 26
        - -   subtract -> x-26 (truthy when x=27 as only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
```

Comment: This is probably just sheer luck, but you can replace `27Q` with `₂-`, which saves a byte.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Shocking that 26 has its own byte; how are there enough bytes for everything else?!

Comment: Yeah, I believe we had some spare constants left after the rewrite and after some analysis, we came to the conclusion that **26** (_no. of letters in the alphabet_) seemed to be used commonly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ÆfQƑa%ɗ4⁼3,3µ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1rgsYmJqienmzxq3GOsY3xoq/L//6YA)

Outputs the first \$n\$ Blum integers. Takes \$n\$ on STDIN

-1 byte thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)

### How it works

```
ÆfQƑa%ɗ4⁼3,3µ# - Main link. Takes no arguments
            µ  - Group the previous links into a monad f(k):
Æf             -   Prime factors of k; F
      ɗ4       -   Previous 3 links as a dyad g(F, 4):
  QƑ           -     Are the prime factors unique?
     %         -     Mod each factor by 4
    a          -     And; If the prime factors are unique, yield the
                      factors mod 4, otherwise, yield 0
        ⁼3,3   -   Does that equal [3, 3]?
             # - Read n. Count up k = 0, 1, ... until n such k return true under f(k)
```

Comment: -1 byte: `ÆfQƑa%ɗ4⁼3,3µ#`

Comment: @NickKennedy Ah, nice use of `a`! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>59</s>  57 bytes

This version is inspired by [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230055/58563) in Python. We print `n` if the concatenation of its proper divisors modulo 4 (in ascending order and without repetition) is `"133"`.

```javascript
for(n=0;g=d=>--d&&g(d)+[[d%4][n%d]];)g(++n)^133||print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPP1sA63TbF1k5XN0VNLV0jRVM7OjpF1SQ2Ok81JTbWWjNdQ1s7TzPO0Ni4pqagKDOvRCNP8/9/AA)

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>76</s>  75 bytes

Prints the sequence 'forever' (i.e. until a recursion error occurs).

```javascript
for(n=0;g=d=>k%--d?g(d):d;)g(k=p=g(k=++n))*g(k=n/p)^p!=k|~(p&k)&3||print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoAgEADAt3RIdgsp6BLJ1k8CSRITtsWik/R1o8swh33staUgt37GUvYzAVNvPDmaY621Wzw4nJxBD5GEftuWEZt/3AmuUlHML4iKqIacJQW@gbGUDw)

#### Commented

```javascript
for(               // loop:
  n = 0;           //   start with n = 0
  g = d =>         //   define the helper function g
    k % --d ? g(d) //   which returns the highest proper divisor of k
            : d;   //
)                  //
  g(               // get the highest proper divisor of ...
    k = p =        //   ... the highest proper divisor p of ...
      g(k = ++n)   //     ... n, after it's been incremented
  ) *              // and multiply it by
  g(               // the highest proper divisor of
    k = n / p      //   k = n / p
  )                // this product is either 1 (success) or greater than 1
  ^ p != k         // make sure that p is not equal to k
                   // (so the product XOR'ed with p != k must give 0)
  | ~(p & k) & 3   // make sure that both p and k are congruent to 3 mod 4
  || print(n)      // print n if all tests pass
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 134 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p=[],s=2:sorted(i*j for j in p for i in p if i<j)[:n]if n<len(p)else f(n,p+[s]*(all(s%i for i in range(2,s))and s%4>2),s+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxDoIwEIDhV7mF5A66WDQxBHwR0qGGVo/Uo@mx@PSV6OD2Lf@f3/tzk/6aS61xSv51XzyIydPsjE520K3sYUFuV4hbgRVYIH/JP3IEHleaB3EHZUxBMFNIGiDiMepmdS36lFAb/ofFyyOgNUrkZQFtzjdLRrsT1VxYdox46YnqBw)

Output the first n numbers of the sequence.

### Explanation

Creates a list of primes `p` starting with the empty list. First, check if `p` has more than `n` elements (this is frankly quite arbitrary, we clearly need less primes than that.)

If there are, then we output the first `n` elements of the sorted list of products `i*j` for each possible duo of `i` and `j` in `p` if i<j to prevent duplicates.

Otherwise check if the counter is `s` is prime. Recall `f` with `n` and either p unchanged if s is composite or `p+[s]` if s is prime. Also increment `s`.

Remove the colon before n to get a program which outputs the nth Blum integer, 0-indexed.

Log: 151->150->142->139->138->137->134

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ḋĊ≠%₄ᵛ3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG6ieKKpf/huIvEiuKJoCXigoThtZszJv//)

Acts as an infinite generator.

### Explanation

```
ḋĊ≠%₄ᵛ3&
ḋ         The input's prime decomposition
 Ċ        is a pair
  ≠       of distinct values
   ᵛ      which all
    %₄    modulo 4
      3   equal 3.
       &  The input and the output are the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>118</s> 112 bytes

Prints the first `n` Blum integers.

```python
n=input()
P=4
k=3
r=p=[]
while p[n:]<=p:
 if P%k&k/2:r=r+[x*k for x in p];p+=k,
 P*=k*k;k+=1
print sorted(r)[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDoIwDADQe7@iFw0wEwE9DfsPuy@7CWGp6Zo6I379fE9/dS8ytyaURT@16yHQHZhuYKQUE3z3/FpRo/j0IPWAecNw4jNfZ29kLh4D41YMD8yCmhZ1xBfAMBAPvLCjCdSyVHwXq@uzsz56Sa1N4/gH)

Uses [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). `p` keeps track of all primes of the form \$4t+3\$, `r` is a unique list of all Blum integers that can be created with the primes in `p`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＦＮ«≦⊕χＷ⁻³¹↨⁴﹪Φχ∧μ¬﹪χλ⁴≦⊕χ»Ｉχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY27CgIxFETrzVfc8gZiIabbahWELbL4CzGJbiCPJQ8txG@PEayd5sAcmFGrTCpK19otJsA5bLUs1V9NQkrhRQYhtylnew/dqWS8CcVoBoqOZHiu1hlAYUPNeNgzOMpskDMQUVcX8Wxd6UOKwRQ0egZLLPhzvXS0hwH/Av78vMkl2VDwJHNBRenYGm@7h/sA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop the given number of times.

```
≦⊕χ
```

Increment the result variable (predefined to `10`, which is fortunately less than the first Blum integer).

```
Ｗ⁻³¹↨⁴﹪Φχ∧μ¬﹪χλ⁴
```

Take the proper factors of the variable, reduce them modulo `4`, interpret the list as a base `4` integer, and repeat while the result is not `31` (`133` in base 4)...

```
≦⊕χ
```

... increment the result variable.

```
»Ｉχ
```

Output the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 61 bytes

Prints all Blum integers.

```
0|while(1;.+1)|select([[.%range(2;.)]|indices(0)[]%4]==[1,1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADA1wgrlbjRTXyJeAhbyhAtDbr49raZ82bW/T1iIkCjBpS9UaLwgHNK1DXvBLNR0veYtxiogZbOi8Vb63BEL5m/cj2x5MZTrj8)

For all practical reasons `0|while(1;.+1)` could be replaced with `range(0|-y0)`, but it feels more like an infinite sequence this way, even if both are limited by the range of representable numbers.